# How to filter a column using multi value parameter list in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS. What I thought should be very simple took me 1 day and I am not able to fix it. All I need is the following

```
Select * from table1 where len(username) <= 6
Select * from table1 where len(username) >= 7
```

I want to display a drop menu with two options Short Username and Long Username.
When a username click the short username the first query result is showed and when the user click Long username the second query result is showed.

What I did so far is I added a parameter list with two values i.e Short parameter list = 6 and Long parameter list = 7. I then added two filters. In the first the expression= len(NameColumn.value)  operator= <= value = @parameter. In the second the expression= len(NameColumn.value) operator= >= value = @parameter. Can you please what can I do to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a similar FILTER in the dataset that @energ1ser mentioned.

You would have a Parameter where the user selects either Long or Short. You might use different values for it.

For the expression, you would use:

```
=IIF( (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "Short" and LEN(FIELDS!USERNAME.VALUE) <= 6) 
   OR (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "Long"  and LEN(FIELDS!USERNAME.VALUE) >= 7), 1, 0)
```

For the type, use **Integer**, and Operator **=** and Value **1**.

This expression calculates each row as **0** or **1** and then filters it for the **1**'s.

To display **ALL** records, add another **OR** for when All is selected for the Parameter.

```
=IIF( (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "Short" and LEN(FIELDS!USERNAME.VALUE) <= 6) 
   OR (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "Long"  and LEN(FIELDS!USERNAME.VALUE) >= 7) 
   OR (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "All"), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thats great, It did the trick. Will it be possible in the current logic to show all the names by default or add an option to show all the names by selecting "both" from the menu?

Comment: yes - just add and extra OR for when YourParameter = "All". 

=IIF( (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "Short" and LEN(FIELDS!USERNAME.VALUE) <= 6) 
   OR (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "Long"  and LEN(FIELDS!USERNAME.VALUE) >= 7) OR (Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "All"), 1, 0)

Answer (score 2):

I think it may work better to do the filtering in the query rather then use the SSRS filters. Try this query.

```
select * from table1 where (@Parameter = 0 and len(username) <= 6) or (@Parameter = 1 and len(username) >= 7)
```

And your parameter could be setup like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use the query when I have a report based on a table and with calculated fields too.